# Weird lein uberwar behavior

Tags: clojure, war, compojure

I'm executing `lein uberwar` for my test webapp and I'm getting the following weird error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol (servlet.clj:1)
```

The servlet.clj contains the following:

```
(ns test.servlet
  (:use ring.util.servlet)
  (:require test.routes :as routes)
  (:gen-class :extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet))

(defservice routes/app-routes)
```

The test.routes file contains:

```
(ns test.routes
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]))


(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] {:status 200
               :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
               :body "<h1>Hello World</h1>"})
  (route/files "/" {:root "static"})
  (ANY "/:s" [s] (str "page-not-found" s)

;; For lein ring-server
;(def test-handler
;  (handler/site app-routes))
```

The strange thing is that if I substitute the line

```
(:require test.routes :as routes)
```

With:

```
(:require test.routes)
```

And call

```
 (defservice test.routes/app-routes)
```

In servlet.clj, the WAR compiles fine and it is working flawlessly in tomcat. Is there some bug in my code that I fail to see? Why do I need to call test.routes/... instead of just routes/...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put it inside a vector:

```
(:require [test.routes :as routes])
```

Comment: @stk You are welcome! Would you mind accepting this answer if it solved your problem?